# I'm making a text-based rpg game but im keep getting "cannot call member function 'void monster::monsterDamage()' without object" message

Tags: c++, object

I'm making a text-based RPG game but I'm keep getting `cannot call member function 'void monster::monsterDamage()' without object` message. Here is my code:

player.cpp

```
#include "player.h"
#include "monster.h"

void player::playerGetDamage()
{
    pHealth -= monster::monsterDamage();
}
```

monster.cpp

```
#include "monster.h"

monster::monster(1)
{
    mName="Rat";
    mHealth=100;
    mAttack=10;
    mExp=50;
}

void monster::monsterGetDamage()
{
    mHealth-=player::playerDamage();
}

void monster::pickMonster()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int a = rand() % 2 + 1;
    if (a == 1)
    {
        monster(1)
    }   

    if (a == 2)
    {
        monster(2)
    }   
}
```

I can't compile: I can't use `mDamage` in player.cpp or `playerDamage()` in monster.cpp. It says `cannot call member function 'void monster::monsterDamage()' without object`

Also, I wanted to choose random enemy with `pickmonster()` but I don't know how to use it. There is `monster::monster(1)` for an example but it seems it's wrong.

Comment: Your player is *interacting with* a monster.  I recommend passing the monster to the player or the player to the monster (probably the latter).

Comment: @Ðаn i did as good as i can.can you look now

Comment: @ThomasMatthews can you open it a bit?

Comment: You have to learn the basics of classes, objects, member functions etc. It is not just one failure - you are using classes and objects in a wrong manner.

Comment: You should have two objects, a player and a monster.  You need instances.  In OO terms, a player can interact with a monster (instance) by invoking a method of the monster.  A monster can interact with a player by invoking a method of the player.  In either case, an instance needs to be passed to a method.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since this is an *object oriented program* you must create a monster before a player can communicate with one. This means that you can't use the following code:

```
void player::playerGetDamage()
{
    pHealth -= monster::monsterDamage();
}
```

It doesn't guarantee that a monster object of the "monster"-class exists. You can make sure that a player object knows that a monster exists by passing a monster object in the parameter.

```
void player::playerGetDamage(const monster& aMonster)
{
    //Use object
    pHealth -= aMonster.monsterDamage();
}
```

You'll get the same type of error in the monster-class too in this function:

```
void monster::monsterGetDamage()
{
    mHealth-=player::playerDamage();
}
```

This can be corrected in the same way by passing a player object in the parameter but then you'll increase the dependency between the classes which might be a problem in the future. Perhaps it's time to reconsider where you handle the objects for the player and the monster?

> and i wanted to choose random enemy with pickmonster() but i dont know how to use it there is monster::monster(1) for an example but it seems its wrong

Currently, your pickMonster-function in the monster-class is creating a new local monster-object *inside itself*. This means that if a monster object calls the function it will create another monster. I think that you want this functionality, to pick a monster, outside of the monster-class to get the behaviour that you want.

As others have stated, your biggest issue overall is that you don't know how to use classes and their objects. These concepts is pretty big for this answer so I suggest that you check out the mentioned ones by cmks; Class, object, member functions.

Further reading:

- [C++ Classes and Objects - TutorialsPoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_classes_objects.htm)
- [Classes (Part 1) - Cplusplus](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/classes/)

Answer (score -1):

The syntax you’re using, `monster::monsterDamage()`, would be correct for a `static` class function.  That’s probably where you saw it used.  Those are functions that don’t apply to any one monster in particular, but are just associated with the `monster` class in general.  They don’t belong to any individual object of the class.  One big difference between member functions that are and aren’t `static` is that a `static` member function does not get called with a `this` pointer, so you can’t use non-static data members or the `this` keyword inside one.  Those are different from object to object, and `static` members are the same for all objects.

The `static` keyword is also used in a completely different way inside functions (to declare that a variable is persistent across all calls to that function, not a temporary that gets created when the function is called and destroyed when it returns) and a third completely different way outside either functions or class definitions (to declare that a symbol is only visible within this source file and files that `#include` it).  Welcome to C++, where the standards committee would rather re-use an existing keyword than break old code by reserving a new keyword.

If you’re familiar with the `<iostream>` and `<stdio.h>` libraries, one example is that there’s a function in the standard library that makes them synchronize, `std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio()`.  You don’t call it on `cout`, `cin` or `cerr` separately; there’s just one function that applies to the entire `<iostream>` library.

The other kind of class member has to be called like this:

```
monster foe;
player bar; // barian?

bar.mHealth -= foe.monsterDamage();
```

The `mHealth` member is not static, so it’s that player’s health, not all players’ health.  But if you were keeping track of all damage done by all monsters in the game, that counter could be a static member of the `monster` class.  How do you determine, inside your call, which monster is doing damage, though?  Probably you want to pass that information in as a parameter, such as:

```
int player::playerGetDamage( monster& foe )
{
    return pHealth -= foe.monsterDamage();
}
```

Then you call it with something like:

```
if ( bar.playerGetDamage(foe) < 1 )
  bar.dies();
```